# How to use functionality of EasyGUI within a tab created by GUI Layout Toolbox?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I am using [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) as well as [EasyGUI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22936) from [MATLAB file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) to develop my GUI. I have created 6 tabs using the [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) and I would like to use the functionality of [EasyGUI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22936) (such as drop down menu, push button etc.) in one of the 6 tabs (say Tab#2). How can I do this?

Doing the following pops up two separate figures which is not what I want:

```
fh = figure('Units', 'normalized', ...
   'OuterPosition', [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.4], ...
   'Toolbar', 'none', 'Menu', 'none');

% ------------------Create Tabs---------------------
p = uiextras.TabPanel('Parent', fh);    % Tab Component

Tab1 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 1st Tab
Tab2 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 2nd Tab - Horiz Box
Tab3 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 3rd Tab - Horiz Box
Tab4 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 4th Tab - Horiz Box
Tab5 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 5th Tab - Horiz Box
Tab6 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 6th Tab - Horiz Box

myGui = Tab2;

freq1 = gui.slider('Frequency 1 (Hz)', [1 40]);
freq2 = gui.slider('Frequency 2 (Hz)', [1 40]);
phaseDiff = gui.numericmenu('Phase difference (degrees)', 0:30:180);
plotType = gui.textmenu('Lissajous plot type', {'2d-phase', '2d-comet'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a closer read at the EasyGUI code, it looks like [`gui.manualgui`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22936-easygui/content/EasyGUI/+gui/manualgui.m) and [`gui.container`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22936-easygui/content/EasyGUI/+gui/container.m) are intended to use the entire figure window as the parent of the GUI, not any other `uicontainer`. (Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see any other files that subclass `gui.container` besides `autogui` and `manualgui`.

HOWEVER, it looks like we are in luck! The `gui.container` code contains the following in its constructor:

```
elseif ishandle(uihandle) && strmatch(get(uihandle,'type'), ...
        {'figure', 'uipanel', 'uicontainer', 'uiflowcontainer', 'uigridcontainer'})
    obj.UiHandle = uihandle;
```

which means that there's a scenario where a `gui.container` object may be created as the child of a `uipanel` object. I modified the `gui.manualgui` constructor to accept a handle graphics object and create a new `uipanel` object instead of a `figure`, then pass it to its superclass constructor:

```
function obj = manualgui(hg)

        if exist('hg', 'var')
            h = uipanel(...
                'Parent', hg);
        else

        h = figure(...
            'Name', 'gui.manualgui', ...
            'BackingStore'      , 'off', ...
            'DockControls'      , 'off', ...
            'NumberTitle'       , 'off', ...
            'MenuBar'           , 'none', ...
            'Resize'            , 'on', ...
            'Visible'           , 'on', ...
            'WindowStyle'       , 'normal');

        end

        obj@gui.container(h);      

    end
```

Then, I added some code in the `gui.container` constructor to account for the fact that some properties of Figures (namely `Color`) are not properties of `uipanels` (namely `BackgroundColor`):

```
function obj = container(uihandle)

        if ~exist('uihandle', 'var')                
            obj.UiHandle = figure();
        elseif ishandle(uihandle)  &&  strcmp(get(uihandle, 'tag'), 'EasyGUIContainer')
            % return the existing instance
            obj = get(uihandle, 'userdata');
            return;
        elseif ishandle(uihandle) && strmatch(get(uihandle,'type'), ...
                 {'figure', 'uipanel', 'uicontainer', 'uiflowcontainer', 'uigridcontainer'})
            obj.UiHandle = uihandle;
        else
            throw(MException('container:InvalidHandle', 'Invalid HG handle'));
        end

        % Backgroundcolor is the same as used by GUIDE
        if ishandle(uihandle) && strcmp(get(uihandle,'type'), ...
                                        'uipanel')
            set(obj.UiHandle, 'units', 'pixels', ...
                              'tag', 'EasyGUIContainer', ...
                              'backgroundcolor', [0.8314    0.8157    0.7843], ...
                              'userdata', obj, ...
                              'DeleteFcn', @(h,e) delete(obj));
        else

            set(obj.UiHandle, 'units', 'pixels', ...
                              'tag', 'EasyGUIContainer', ...
                              'color', [0.8314    0.8157    0.7843], ...
                              'userdata', obj, ...
                              'DeleteFcn', @(h,e) delete(obj));
        end
    end
```

I just tried to instantiate the `freq1` object in your example; this is because I'm now using a `gui.manualgui` object rather than a `gui.autogui` object. You can potentially extend this to work on `autogui`; I did not right now since I'm about to leave work where I have MATLAB available and this is a little less non-trivial to do. Here's the final code I used to make this figure once I made the above modifications:

```
fh = figure('Units', 'normalized', ...
   'OuterPosition', [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.4], ...
   'Toolbar', 'none', 'Menu', 'none');

% ------------------Create Tabs---------------------

p = uiextras.TabPanel('Parent', fh);    % Tab Component

Tab1 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 1st Tab
Tab2 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 2nd Tab - Horiz Box
Tab3 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 3rd Tab - Horiz Box
Tab4 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 4th Tab - Horiz Box
Tab5 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 5th Tab - Horiz Box
Tab6 = uiextras.HBox('Parent', p);          % 6th Tab - Horiz Box

myGui = gui.manualgui(Tab2);
freq1 = gui.slider('Frequency 1 (Hz)', [1 40], myGui);
% freq2 = gui.slider('Frequency 2 (Hz)', [1 40]);
% phaseDiff = gui.numericmenu('Phase difference (degrees)', 0:30:180);
% plotType = gui.textmenu('Lissajous plot type', {'2d-phase', '2d-comet'});
```

And here's the result:

[image: EasyGUI widget on top of a GUI Layout Toolbox HBox]

Obviously since I'm using `manualgui` rather than `autogui` you'd have to either manually place the slider yourself, or modify `autogui` to make it use the correct handle graphics object.

Comment: See my radical update. Took some finagling but I figured out the modifications required to make this work. I don't have the time to extend this to `autogui` but you can certainly set your widget locations manually in the correct tab box. I'll give modifying the `autogui` code a crack tomorrow. (As an aside, I'm deleting all previous comments to keep chatter from getting confusing, and you should consider doing the same.)

Comment: Thanks, Dang. Do you think modifying the `autoGUI` codes as above affect it's original functionality anywhere? 
I'll check your solution tomorrow and see how it works.

Comment: Looking through it, the only modification you (or I) need to make is to flip through `varargin` to check for a particular param/value setting, something like `Parent` (*before* the figure would typically be created). Then have a small `if/else` to either pass a `figure` or a `uipanel` object to the superclass constructor, along with other required parameters.

Comment: These modifications should *not* impact the ability to place `gui.widget` objects, because the parents of those objects are the `autogui` or `manualgui` objects; the widgets themselves have no idea that they're not in a Figure window. That said, there will likely be modifications to the `autogui` code you need to make to ensure that widgets will properly fit in the `uipanel`. But I think you can manage that, right? :)

Comment: Dang, I am very new to the GUI programming, so I would appreciate if you can suggest what changes to make and where. The changes suggested for `manualgui` works...thanks! :)

Comment: I am looking through it this morning. All of `autogui`'s functionality is based on the fact that the parent is supposed to be a figure. You're better off using `manualgui` for your needs because there is a whole lot of tweaking that you need to do. I would contact the author of the EasyGUI API and ask him to see if he could implement an `autogui` that can accept a `uipanel` as parent.